# SOSL use FIND with bind list of Strings - Specified search expression can not be converted to string

Tags: apex, list, sosl, execute-anonymous

I have a list of strings (phones) which I'm trying to use inside my SOSL Find clause and its giving me issues:

```
List<String> phonesList = new List<String>();
for(Account acc : acclist) {
        phonesList.add(acc.Phone);
}
System.debug(phonesList.size());
System.debug(phonesList[0]);
```

Until this point I can see the string, let's call it: `1112223333`

When I try to use the `phonesList[]` inside a SOSL like this one:

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND :phonesList IN PHONE FIELDS Returning Account(Id, Name)];
```

I'm getting the next error in Execute Anonymous:

> Specified search expression can not be converted to string

The Anonymous error line refers to the SOSL line.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm#i1423049), "A search query includes the literal word or phrase and can also include wildcards and logical operators (AND, OR, and AND NOT)".

Comment: Thank you, I saw the docs but it still fails. If I set only one string in the `FIND {term}` it works, but not the bind, although there are examples of binding: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm

Comment: the binding examples for collections you cite apply to SOQL; you'll need your bind variable to look like `val1 OR val2 OR val3 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of achieving this with SOSL is to pre-build the `searchQuery` as if it was using the `OR` operator.

You will need to do some cleansing before you start building the `searchQuery`, additional characters may need to be substituted depending on your data. If not complete, I expect you to receive an exception along the lines of `System.QueryException: line x:xx mismatched character ...`.

```
List<String> phonesList = new List<String>();
for(Account acc : acclist) {
    phonesList.add(acc.Phone.replace('-', ' ').replace('+', ' '));
}
```

Now it's time to work through your `phonesList` and start building the `searchQuery`. You may wish to tidy this logic up with another loop variation. We are expecting a result like `numberOne OR numberTwo OR numberXX`.

```
String concatenatedNumbers = '';

for (Integer i=0; i<=phonesList.size()-1; i++) {
    if (i == phonesList.size() - 1) {
        concatenatedNumbers = concatenatedNumbers + ' OR ' + phonesList[i];
    } else if (String.isEmpty(concatenatedNumbers)) {
        concatenatedNumbers = phonesList[i];
    } else {
        concatenatedNumbers = concatenatedNumbers + ' OR ' + phonesList[i] + ' ';
    }
}
```

And then we put it all to action. The [search](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_search.htm) system class allows us to call a dynamic SOSL using `query()`.

```
String query = 'FIND {' + concatenatedNumbers + '} IN PHONE FIELDS Returning Account(Id, Name)';
List<List<SObject>> searchList = search.query(query);
```